# Prototypical Inheritance - Why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
example = {};

example.Math = {
  sin: function() {console.log('sin');},
  cos: function() {console.log('cos');}
};

foo = function(){
   sin(); 
};
foo.prototype = window.example.Math;

console.log(foo.prototype)
console.log(foo.cos)
console.log(foo())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mubqy/9/

From what I thought I understood references are searched for through the scope chain. So theoretically if I assign an object with functions defined to a prototype I should get all of those functions and fields of the object or so I thought.  Where is the error in my understanding? Neither of the above scenarios work. Additionally the internal *proto* variable is not being updated. Obviously that's why it is not working, but why doesn't my assignment to the prototype work?

Comment: It would need to be `this.sin();`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? See http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: Objects don't inherit from their own [`prototype`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.5) property, but from their constructor's (also called their internal [`[[Prototype]]`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) property).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to realize that the prototyped method needs to be run with the `new` keyword, and it needs to use `this` to access its variables and methods, like this:

```
example = {};

example.Math = {
  sin: function() {console.log('sin');},
  cos: function() {console.log('cos');}
};

foo = function(){
   this.sin(); 
};
foo.prototype = window.example.Math;

console.log(foo.prototype)
console.log(foo.cos)
console.log(new foo())
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed two very crucial aspects of prototype.

- A prototype acts as the parent of the object
- You must initiate an instance of your object

First, use the keyword `this` to access object's methods and variables:

```
var foo = function(){
   this.sin(); 
};
```

Than initiate an instance of the object using the keyword `new`:

```
new foo();
```

Just like OOP, only not :)

http://jsfiddle.net/46fPe/

Comment: A prototype is in no way a "parent" of an object. It is simply a mechanism for inheritance.

Comment: As far as my terminology goes, a parent (super) in OOP is the class you inherited from (extended). Correct me if my perspective is wrong.